# Combine extend and mixin in with same rules

Tags: css, sass, extend, mixins

Okey!
I have couple of extends in sass like

```
%heading
%paragraph
%gutter
```

and so on...

I want to reuse thouse in media queries, but that doesnt work. I know that.

Then i came up with the idea to have all my extends as mixins too. So when i want them in a media query i simply use mixin. for example

```
.my-widget {
    @extend %gutter;
    @media.... {
        @include gutter-other;
    }
}
```

and because i dont want to write all my rules again. How do i write my sass then?

I tried

```
%my-extend, @mixin my-extend {
   ...
}
```

but that didnt work.

**Any ideas how to work with this?**

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't combine them that way.  You'll have to write a mixin that is invoked by your extend class and anything inside of a media query.

```
@mixin my-extend {
    background: yellow;
}

%my-extend {
    @include my-extend;
}

.foo {
    @extend %my-extend;
}

.bar {
    @extend %my-extend;
}

.baz {
    @media (min-width: 30em) {
        @include my-extend;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.foo, .bar {
  background: yellow;
}

@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .baz {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```