# How do I prevent abusing the placeholders in SASS but still get the desired outcome?

Tags: css, sass

I've just started learning SASS and I got the hang of it pretty quickly, however it feels like I'm writing my placeholders in a bad fashion so I want to understand how to avoid abusing them before I proceed.

I figured that it would be smart to put a bunch of placeholders like I've done below:

```
%margins {
    margin: $margin;
    padding: $padding;
}

%border {
    border: $border $lightgrey;
}

%positionRel {
    position: $relativePos;
}
```

So that I get this outcome:

```
body, #info-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }

#container, #info-container input:nth-child(1) {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey; }

#container, #info-container {
    position: relative; }
```

But it just seems really, really wrong to do it like this because there's gonna be a ton of placeholders in bigger projects. If I use mixins instead the attributes won't be shared. Or should I use placeholders within a mixin and pass in arguments that the placeholders use? Please tell me, what's the best approach for letting elements share styles without overly abusing placeholders?

Comment: By 'placeholders', do you mean [variables](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-2)?

Comment: @Larz No.  [extend-only selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders)

Comment: It's not clear here why you think mixins are not a viable choice here.

Comment: Because then I won't have for example: body, #info { margin: 0; }, instead I would have body { margin: 0; } and #info { margin: 0; }, and that's bad isn't it?

Comment: Only if you choose to write it that way.  There's no reason why you can't have #info extend body (or vice versa).  Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583004/combine-extend-and-mixin-in-with-same-rules

Comment: @cimmanon But my question comes down to, is it bad to have a bunch of placeholders for single attributes? Like position: relative/absolute, font-size: 1.2em etc. Since there are many elements sharing these usually it seems appropriate to write it like that, no?

Comment: Good/bad is pretty subjective.  You want to make choices based on what is going to make the smallest compiled file.  There are times where combining selectors will be smaller, other times it will be bigger.  [This CR answer might help](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/27910/26722).